# Problem to request data from express server with Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have an application in react on my domain with a server in Express.The project is divided into two sections (folders), "Frontend" and "Backend". When I start the express server it listens on port 4000, but when the application in React makes the request with axios through the path Ex:("`https://localhost.com/dataRequested`") get the 404 error. When I add the port to the domain of the listening server, the request work. Ex:("`https://localhost.com:4000/dataRequested`")

**Index.js server Express**

```
const routesHandler = require('./routes/handler.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt', 'utf8');

const credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', routesHandler);

const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(4000);
```

**handler.js route server Express**

```
router.get('/randomElementsData', (req, res) =>
{
  //functions
}
```

**hero.js component React app**

```
const getHeroData = async () =>
{
   try
   {
      const response = await axios.get('/randomElementsData');
      setDataHero(response);
   }
   catch (error)
   {
      console.log(error);
   }
}
```

Comment: did you add the proxy in package.json? 
 "proxy": "http://localhost:4000"

Comment: Since it works when you add the port to the API call... i would say you need to add the proxy in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your package.json file

```
"proxy" : "http://localhost:4000"
```

this is used by react to send all  fetch/axios requests to the node server (only in development). Then the node server should know whether to forward that request to the Reactjs router or to the express router

I add "/api" before all of my API calls to help express figure out which router to use

```
app.use('/api', routesHandler);

// All other GET requests not handled before will return our React app

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(<the location of your build folder>);
// res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/build'));
});
```

and now your axios call will look like

```
axios.get('/api/randomElementsData')
```

Your Nginx Reverse proxy should look like this

```
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

Comment: Yes this works at the development level, but now the application in React is a build and the "package.json" file is not there. I also tried to upload the file in the build but it doesn't go the same

Comment: i edited my answer... see if any of that helps you

Comment: I have updated the code, but nothing has changed. Requests are not listened to on port 4000

Comment: @Garw where are you hosting the React app and the NodeJS server? Are they both on the same server?

Comment: They are both on the same server and the same "public_html" folder of my domain.

Comment: how are you running the node server? PM2?

Comment: I use "npm" command for start server

Comment: Did you configure the reverse proxy on the server? Are you using Nginx or Apache? CEntOS or Ubuntu? Sorry for all of the questions.

Comment: Don't worry about the questions. I've actually tried a lot of things, it's my first app in React and I don't know how to approach it yet. Same thing for node js. The server goes to Ubuntu anyway.

Comment: and your proxy server is xginx or apache?

Comment: I use "nodemon" for start express server. Command: "nodemon index.js". I don't have proxy server

Comment: This thread is getting long. where is the best place to PM you ?

Comment: I don't know, you want my email?

Comment: benningkeaton@gmail.com

Comment: I solved the problem anyway, I installed pm2 and nginx following a guide I set the proxy. Thank you for suggesting it to me.
Guide: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

Probably CORS issue if the react app is stand alone..

try adding this to express app

```
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', `http://${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT_CLIENT}`) // update to match the domain you will make the request from
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
      res.header(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Auth-Token'
      )
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT')
      if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(204).send()
      } else {
        next()
      }
    })
```

Comment: I added the code but nothing has changed

Comment: dont think you need cors if its on the same domain

Comment: do you have any console.errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting the endpoint
`http://localhost:4000/dataRequested`

This may even be because of URL being Invalid